# Shift columns but retain headers

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Good afternoon,

I have a worksheet 'Example' with two blank columns that contain headers (B & C), and two data-containing columns that have no headers (E & F).

I want to be able to use VBA to shift columns to the left without affecting the headers (like using 'Range("B:B,C:C").Delete' but without getting rid of the 'Job' & 'City' headers). As below:

From this -

```
 A        B        C         D              E               F
Name     Job     City     Country               
----------------------------------------------------------------
Andrew                    Doctor        Manchester     England
George                    Lawyer        New York       America 
Paul                      Engineer      Birmingham     England
Carl                      Technician    London         England
Joe                       Optician      Detroit        America
```

To this -

```
 A          B               C             D            E             F
Name       Job            City         Country               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Andrew    Doctor        Manchester     England
George    Lawyer        New York       America 
Paul      Engineer      Birmingham     England
Carl      Technician    London         England
Joe       Optician      Detroit        America
```

I hope this makes sense. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Thank-you.

Comment: Or just highlight the cells `B2:C100` or whatever your last row is and select Delete -> Shift Cells Left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Example").Range("B2:C99999").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```